# Does the fact that you look like a guy who committed a crime constitute grounds for detention?

Tags: arrest, fifth-amendment

Does the fact that you look like a guy who committed a crime constitute grounds for detention?  In other words, can you be pulled over for looking like a suspect who committed some crime and for no other reason?

Comment: Yes.  You can even be arrested for reasonably matching the description of a criminal suspect.  References supporting this answer can be readily found through search engine.

Comment: Ok, but certainly you can't be detained just because you're black and male and a guy who robbed a bank last week was black and male? That's what I'm driving at.

Comment: We've answered this [here](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/8571/are-generalized-descriptions-of-suspects-considered-lawfully-admissable/8574#8574): the officer would need a "particularized and objective basis for suspecting the particular person stopped of . . . criminal activity". Merely being black and male will not be held to be sufficiently particularized.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a black man, you don't look like every other black man. If you are driving around in a car like many, many other people, then being black and male doesn't give any reasonable grounds to believe that you would be the black male person suspected of a crime that the police is looking for.

On the other hand, if the police officer has a picture of the criminal, and reasonably good eyes, and you do indeed look like the criminal, yes of course you can be detained.

And if a crime happened, and the police managed to close off the crime scene and hold every single person who could have committed the crime, and there is evidence that a black male committed the crime, and you are the only black male present, then you have a problem. You would have the same problem if you were the only white female present, and there was evidence that a white female committed the crime.